# Why can I assign a value of another type to a variable of empty class type?

Tags: typescript

I can write something like this and the compiler doesn't swear that I assigned a value of another type to a variable of empty class type:

```js
class MyClass {}

const myClass: MyClass = new Date() //???
```

but, for example, if I assign the `Date` value to the `Boolean` variable, the compiler will say that this is an error:

```js
const b: Boolean = new Date() 
/*
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'Boolean'.
  The types returned by 'valueOf()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
*/
```

It turns out that TypeScript doesn't check the types themselves, but only the properties inside the type?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html - a `new Date()` has all of the (no) properties a `MyClass` instance needs.

Comment: `MyClass` instances have zero properties. Therefore `Date` instances have all properties that are are required to be treated like a `MyClass`.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5451